# Has many through

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

A `Venue` has many `Subscriptions`.

A `Subscription` has many `Subscribers` (`User`).

Theres a pivot table, containing the relation between user_id and subscription_id.

[image: Pivot for subscription and user_id]

How can I get all `Subscribers` from a `Venue`?

I have tried with:

```
class Venue {
    /**
     * Members
     */

        public function members() {
            return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Subscription');
        }
}
```

But it fails with MySQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.subscription_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `sub
    scriptions`.`venue_id` from `users` inner join `subscriptions` on `subscriptions`.`id` = `users`.`subscription_id` where `
    users`.`deleted_at` is null and `subscriptions`.`venue_id` = 1)
```

How my Subscription model look:

```
`Subscription`

class Subscription extends Model {

    protected $table = 'subscriptions';

    /**
     * Subscripers
     */

        public function subscribers() {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
        }

    /**
     * Venue
     */

        public function venue() {
            return $this->belongsTo('Venue');
        }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is a `Subscription` in your application? To me it sounds like you want to achieve that an `User` can subscribe to a `Venue`, but that would be a n:m relation without an additional `Subscription` model (not sure if you could use one additionally though). Additional information could be stored as pivot elements.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have a pivot table containing the relation between a user and subscription.

Comment: Its because your concept is wrong. You don't need the Subacription model, because you can have a direct n:m mapping between User and Venue. Have a look into the documentation for many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Simple question: Why are you using a third model for `Subscriptions`? It sounds like a normal n:m relation between `User` and `Venue`, as already written in the comments above.

```
class User {
    public function venues() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Venue');
    }
}

class Venue {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

This constellation actually needs three tables, which are (i gave each model a column `name`):

```
users
  - id
  - name

venues
  - id
  - name

user_venue
  - user_id
  - venue_id
```

But to access the relations, you can simply use the Eloquent magic:

```
// List of all venues (as Venue models) that are in relation with User with id $id
$venues = User::find($id)->venues()->get();

// Returns the alphabetically first user that has a relation with Venue with id $id
$user = Venue::find($id)->users()->orderBy('name', 'asc')->first();
```

If you need to store additional information in the pivot table (e.g. when the relation has been established), you can use additional pivot fields:

```
user_venue
  - user_id
  - venue_id
  - created_at

class User {
    public function venues() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Venue')->withPivot('created_at');
    }
}

class Venue {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('created_at');
    }
}

// Returns the date of the relations establishment for the alphabetically
// first Venue the User with id $id has a relation to
$created_at = User::find($id)->venues()->orderBy('name', 'asc')->first()->pivot->created_at;
```

---

I've never tried to do whatever you are trying to do there, because it seems (with the current information) conceptually wrong. I also don't know if it is possible to set up an own model for a pivot table, but I think it should work if the pivot table has an own primary id column. It could probably be helpful if you've a third model that needs to be connected with a connection of two others, but normally that doesn't happen. So try it with pivot tables, like shown above, first.

---

Alright, I still don't see a good use case for this, but I can provide you a query that works. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get an Eloquent query working, but the solution should be still fine though.

```
class Venue {
    public function members($distinct = true) {
        $query = User::select('users.*')
            ->join('subscription_user', 'subscription_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('subscriptions', 'subscriptions.id', '=', 'subscription_user.subscription_id')
            ->where('subscriptions.venue_id', '=', $this->id);
         if($distinct === true) {
             $query->distinct();
         }
         return $query;
     }
}
```

The relation can be queried just as normal:

```
Venue::find($id)->members()->get()
// or with duplicate members
Venue::find($id)->members(false)->get()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I am trying to achieve. I don't want a venue_user relation, because a `User` belongs to a venue, ONLY, if the `User` has a `Subscription` with the `Venue`. My database relation: http://www.laravelsd.com/share/AAjuYS

Comment: Please provide more information on what a Subscription is, what it does (or stand for) and what other information it contains.

Comment: I got this. But what are you trying to achieve? Why does a venue need many subscription and each of them many users? What is, not technically speaking, the point for that?

Comment: Because a User can choose to have many different Subscriptions with a Venue. I need a way to see all Users related to a Venue. A User is related to a Venue if they have a Subscription with them.

Comment: I updated my answer again. Please check if it works for you.